# How to get List<String> from List<Object[]> by converting first element of array to String

Tags: java, java-8

How to get `List<String>` from `List<Object[]>` by converting the first element of array to String?

I tried writing like below but casting is not happening,

```
List<String> results = query.getResultList()
.stream()
.map(result ->{
 Object[]  temp =  (Object[]) result;
 return temp[0].toString();
})
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Below image shows type of results list 
[image]
I am getting Error:java: incompatible types: java.lang.Object cannot be converted to java.util.List.
How to do this correctly using Java 8?

Comment: Back up two steps here.  First, what is the precise result of `getResultList()`?  Second, what framework are you using to do these queries (JPA, Hibernate), and can you use a type-safe approach?

Comment: If you want a list why are you returning only the first element? Groovy?

Comment: What do you mean "casting is not happening"? What is happening?

Comment: Why do you query multiple fields if you just want one? What's the query?

Comment: Looks right to me.  What's wrong?

Comment: @Makoto the precise result of getResultList() is List<Object[]>, this query is of type FullTextQuery from hibernate search with projection.

Comment: @teja1905 Could you post the `query` also? It seems `getResultList()` is not returning `List<Object[]>` but `List<Object>`

Comment: Okay, so...what specific error are you getting back, and again - can you use a type-safe approach?  Recent versions of Hibernate and JPA support `TypedQuery`.

Comment: @K139 I have attached result type picture could please check and suggest

Comment: @teja1905 show us type picture of `query.getResultList()`, not `results`

Comment: @MrinalK.Samanta the type picture is of `query.getResultList()`

Comment: Well the following code works fine, supposedly that query.getResultList() is List<Object[]> as you imply. Sorry for the formatting... `public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Object[]> queryList = new ArrayList<>();
        queryList.add(new Object[]{"Java Core"});

        List<String> results = queryList
                .stream()
                .map(result ->{
                    Object[]  temp =  (Object[]) result;
                    return temp[0].toString();
                })
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(results.get(0));
    }`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`query.getResultList()` returns raw List. As mentioned by @Makoto in comment, try to use type-safe API.
But if you intend to use the current API, add type casting (which will generate warning though).

```
List<String> results = ((List<Object[]>) query.getResultList())
.stream()
.map(result -> result[0].toString())
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```